# Is there a swift protocol which Array and ArraySlice both implement

Tags: arrays, swift

What type should I use in swift 5 if I want a function to accept either a `[Double]` or an `ArraySlice<Double>`?

In other words, is there some type I can use which would allow me to combine both of the following declarations into one, so that the function can be called with one or the other?

```
func appendToX(_ data: ArraySlice<Double>) 
func appendToX(_ data: [Double])
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/randomaccesscollection

Comment: @pnadeau you should edit your question and add where is your method gonna be declared and its purpose. What is X?

Comment: There isn't much of a point to `appendToX`, because `RangeReplaceableCollection` already has `append(contentsOf:)`

Comment: appendToX, is not from my actual code.  I sort of obfuscated it.  You could say part of the interface requirements of my actual function are isomorphic with appendToX's.  My actual code is part of a stream oriented data processing pipeline which will receive slices of Double as input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MartinR said in the comment, they both conform to `RandomAccessCollection` protocol, but you need to use generics in your function due to the fact that `RandomAccessCollection` has Self or associated type requirements:

```
func appendToX<T: RandomAccessCollection>(_ data: T) where T.Element == Double, T.Index == Int {

}
```

Comment: Great, that looks fine, but I'm having trouble writing simple arithmetic expressions with the indices to the 'RandomAccessCollection'.  For example in the following code: `for n in  data.startIndex..<rrIntervals.endIndex-1` gives the error: Cannot convert value of type 'T.Index' to expected argument type 'Int'

Comment: @pnadeau you have to specify that the `Index` type is `Int` to do that. I updated my answer.

Comment: I see thx.  It's nice that it's possible, but that declaration is becoming kind of bonkers!

Comment: @pnadeau yes, it's kind of weird. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @pnadeau, you can also do this more generally `for n in data.indices`, so you wouldn't need to specify that the `Index` is an `Int`

Comment: @NewDev He substracted one from the end index, so that's better expressed as `for n in data.indices.dropLast()`

Comment: Good points on avoiding specifying that the index is an Int, but it my case I have to actually perform arithmetic with it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Swift 5.6

Thanks to several recent improvements to Swift's generics UI, you can replace your original two function declarations with the following:

```swift
func appendToX(_ data: any RandomAccessCollection<Double>)
```